# where do unspent outputs come from?

Tags: output

This post asks the same question: [What is an "unspent output"?](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/4301/what-is-an-unspent-output) but the answers for me are completely incomprehensible, probably because I lack a key piece of knowledge.

I have read every article I can find on "unspent outputs" and with each I get more confused.  e.g. these:

https://www.r3.com/blog/2017/07/18/what-is-a-utxo/

https://bitcointalk.org/index.php?topic=2011399.0

Lets say I have 1 BTC in a coinbase wallet or similar.

Do I have any unspent outputs yet?

If yes, who created it?

If no, how does one create an unspent output (or in what circumstance/use case are they created?

Can a single address have more than one unspent output?  If so in which circumstance?

Is there some article which explains these fundamentals in layman terms?

This one is on the general subject but doesnt mention unclaimed outputs:

https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/Transaction

It says this:

> An output contains instructions for sending bitcoins. Value is the
>   number of Satoshi (1 BTC = 100,000,000 Satoshi) that this output will
>   be worth when claimed.

What is the relationship between claimed and unspent?

Is unspent unclaimed?

How does one claim unclaimed outputs, and in what circumstance would they end up unclaimed?

Comment: Further information also in this thread : https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/69869/what-happens-to-utxos-when-a-transaction-output-script-is-satisfied

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are just puzzling your self. We will start step by step.

**What is Bitcoin output?**

An output is an amount that was sent (via a standard transaction) to a Bitcoin address.
So when I send some bitcoins the recipient address is output address and if the recipient didn't spend the input I sent, it will be unspent output.

**What is the relationship between claimed and unspent?**

it's just the status of the output.

**Do I have any unspent outputs yet?**

No, You have one input. and the sender has "unspent output" which belongs to you.

**If no, how does one create an unspent output (or in what circumstance/use case are they created?**

When you make a transaction, you are creating outputs.
Unspent or claimed is whether the recipient spent the bitcoins or not.

**Can a single address have more than one unspent output? If so in which circumstance?**

outputs do not belong to addresses, but transactions. and a single transaction can have more than one output (e.g.) if you were sending for more than one address in same time.

**Is there some article which explains these fundamentals in layman terms?**

Mastering Bitcoin book.

Comment: Very helpful!  The crux is that if someone sends me 1BTC, then They seem to have an the unspent output, not me. I thought i would have the unspent output. What do I have, an unspent input?

Comment: Exactly, They will have unspent output if they didn't spend the coins you sent. You will have nothing but you had 1 BTC as input and you made an output from that input.