# Merkle root vs message digest?

Tags: merkle-tree

My question is in relation to the operational difference between a **merkle root** and a plain old **message digest**.

To calculate a **merkle root** I need to complete the following steps :

- hash each transaction in a block
- create a merkle tree from all the hashed transactions
- work back up the merkle tree hashing pairs of transactions until I calculate the merkle root

To create a plain old **message digest** I would do the following :

- Take all transactions in a block hash them at the same time to create a message digest

My question is, how is a merkle root more beneficial from an operational standpoint than a plain old message digest?

Answer (score 1):

Initially, they appear the same, only considering that there is a hash included in the block.

A Merkle Tree is more efficient to prove a transaction is included in a block since otherwise, it is necessary to have and hash each transaction to prove a transaction is included using a message digest, so a full node can do this, but an SPV client (and a pruned node looking outside the blocks it has kept) cannot.

There is some more information on how this works in these answers: [Merkle Root and Merkle Proofs](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/69018/merkle-root-and-merkle-proofs)

Comment: So both a message digest and a merkle root provide the same function, but a merkle root is more efficient?

Comment: @T-Pane Not completely the same function, only initially. If I have Message Digest I cannot change one single thing, as you understand the same is true for Merkle Tree but, I can walk a Merkle Tree. The technique is given in this [answer](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/a/69166/75001).