# how do bitcoin nodes detect a transaction?

Tags: address, network, protocol

I have a number of question about bitcoin but I was ask to do specific research on two questions and I figured this would be a good place to start. The first I have answered already the second is: "what is the protocol or code used to identify BTC addresses from other activity on the web?". I'm honestly not sure this question even asks for the correct information but if any of you could answer or point me in the right direction that would be much appreciated.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How transaction happen in blockchain?](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/106131/how-transaction-happen-in-blockchain)

Comment: It clarifies the question. How does the internet/nodes/ISP know where to send and what is a bitcoin transaction? specifically if you have a paper wallet you need software to write down and store the information to be printed and then translate that back into something the system understands. what is that? what is it called and how does it work? I think its just regular internet protocol but i don't know. relatedly, your wallet is listening for after you make a transaction for those that are "published" how does it disseminate between bitcoin communications and other internet chatter?

Comment: Does one of these answer your question: https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/q/3536/5406, https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/q/32237/5406, https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/q/70621/5406