# How do nodes fetch unconfirmed transactions?

Tags: blockchain, python, cryptography, mining-software

I'm taking up a project to build a software in python to mine cryptocurrency (preferably bitcoin).
I have an overview of the computation that needs to be done.

I would like to know how nodes fetch unconfirmed transactions.

Comment: I think that's too big a question to be answerable here. You could break your question down into much smaller parts and research those separately and ask questions here about specific individual points. See [what is mining](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/q/148/13866) etc.

Comment: @RedGrittyBrick Thanks!

Comment: So, there are three sub problems to focus on here: 1.) Fetching unconfirmed transactions 2.) Finding the nonce for hashing based on the difficulty and creating a new block 3.) Submitting/broadcasting the new block to the network for verification. I'm stuck at subproblem 1 and 3 from a programming point of view.

Comment: You seem to be struggling a little. I will edit your question for you -- though you can do this yourself. If you don't like my edits you can use the "rollback" option under "edit".

Comment: Thanks @RedGrittyBrick for making the question more appropriate. I'm gathering a lot of info from the materials provided.

Answer (score 0):

In brief you would use your Bitcoin libraries functions to perform peer discovery and then periodically communicate with a few peers to collect data.

Your question isn't an exact duplicate of any question I can find but existing answers to the following questions will help:

- [How transaction happen in blockchain?](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/q/106131/13866)
- [How do Bitcoin clients find each other?](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/3536/how-do-bitcoin-clients-find-each-other)
- [How are transactions broadcast to the rest of the network?](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/q/32237/13866)
- [How does a node get information from other nodes?](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/q/70621/13866)

---

Other useful resources

- https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/Protocol_documentation
- https://developer.bitcoin.org/devguide/p2p_network.html
  This covers the following topics

  - Peer discovery
  - Connecting to peers
  - Initial Block download
  - Block broadcasting
  - Transaction broadcasting
    This is the part where your node listens for `inv` messages
    and issues corresponding messages such as `getdata`.